# Деление чисел с неизвестной переменной

Tags: javascript

Напиши функцию, принимающую два числа `a` и `b` и возвращающую целое число `r`, где `a = r * b + k, 0 ≤ k < |b|`

Почему данное решение не подходит?

```js
function divide(a, b) {
  let k = (Math.random() * (Math.abs(b) - 0) + 0);
  return Math.round((k - a) / b);
}

console.log(divide(20, 10));
```

Comment: Куда оно "не подходит"?

Comment: Это называется целая часть от деления. k это остаток. r=Math.floor(a/b)

Answer (score 0):

```
function divide (a, b) {
    if (b === 0)
        return Infinity
    else {
        let k = a % b;
        return (a - k) / b;
    }
}
```

Comment: в js новый тип Infinity?